# WP_Query only ONE post, won't work

Tags: posts, wp-query

No matter what, I CANNOT figure out why WP_Query pulls in all posts, and completely ignores `posts_per_page` ...
I only want to show one post.

```
<?php

$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'post',
'orderby'        => 'date',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>

<div style="padding: 15px;">
    <div class="grid_4 alpha">image</div>
    <div class="grid_7 omega">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="height: 33px; background-color: #5ba4d8; position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 300px; line-height: 33px;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <a href="" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;"><span class="nav-blog-next"></span></a>
</div>

<?php   
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `posts_per_page` to `1` only, not `-1`.

Like this: `'posts_per_page' => 1`

`-1` means all.

Answer (score 6):

From your question title, it sounds like you are trying to only pull one single post. The problem is that you have passed -1 to posts_per_page, which equates tells the query to pull in every single post.

Use:

```
'posts_per_page' => 1
```